# Cross Site callbacks with Javascript (ideally with ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created 2 websites - one is a simple ASP.NET Website and the other an ASP.NET MVC Web Application.

The problem is I need the ASP.NET Website display a view from the ASP.NET MVC Web Application.  The ASP.NET MVC Web Application view contains a form with a single text element and a submit button.  I want to be able to submit the form, post back to the ASP.NET MVC Web Application then callback to my ASP.NET Website to indicate that the call was done.  Something like the following:

[image: Flow]

### ASP.NET MVC Web Application

#### TalkToController

```
public class TalkToController : Controller
{
    [AllowCrossSiteJson]
    public ActionResult Talk()
    {
        var model = new TalkToPost
        {
            SomeText = "Hello there",
            Status = "Not submitted"
        };

        return View("_Talk", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Talk(TalkToPost model)
    {
        model.Status = "Posted";

        return View("_Talk", model);
    }
}
```

#### _Talk View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@model TalkToMe.Web.Models.TalkToPost

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Url = Url.Action("Talk", "TalkTo", null, Request.Url.Scheme) }))
{
    <h1>Hi there from Talk To</h1>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeText)
    <br/>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Status)

    <br/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

}
```

### ASP.NET Website

#### TalkerPage.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TalkerPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="TalkerPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <h2>Result in iFrame</h2>

        <iframe runat="server">
        </iframe>

        <hr/>

        <h2>Result in Container</h2>
        <div id="TalkContainer"></div>

        <hr/>

        <button type="button" onclick="getIt(); return false;">Get It!</button>


    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getIt() {
            //debugger;
            $.get("http://localhost:5911/TalkTo/Talk")
                .done(function (data) {
                    $("#TalkContainer").html(data);

                }).fail(function(data) {
                    //debugger;
                    alert('It Failed');
                });
        }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### What works

So when I click the get it button, the razor view html is loaded into the TalkContainer element as follows:

[image: Output]

Unfortunately, the razor view form is not rendered as the ASP Web Site page has its own form by the looks of it.

The response when you click on the GetIt button is:

```
<form action="/TalkTo/Talk" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#TalkContainer" data-ajax-url="http://localhost:5911/TalkTo/Talk" id="form0" method="post"> <h1>Hi there from Talk To</h1>
    <input id="SomeText" name="SomeText" type="text" value="Hello there" /> <br/>
    Not submitted   <br/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### Questions

1. How can I get a javascript callback into my ASP.NET Website from my ASP.NET MVC Web Application when I click on the Submit button - is it possible?
2. Can it be done using iframes?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible somehow, but only really by going through a server.

Comment: ideally you'd want to implement an API service which triggers the same server-side functionality as this form. Then you can just send JSON back and forth instead of trying to manipulate another GUI.

Comment: @ADyson - I agree unfortunately, the web application has the form I need to fill out.  I've put together a small sample (above), but these forms have 100s of inputs to fill out in the real world - and I cannot move these to the Web Site.  There is a lot more going on behind the Submit button too in the real world.

Comment: Is this Web Site something which you maintain, or a 3rd-party thing? Do you have any control over it?